# zip longest for python 2.7

Tags: json, file, python-2.7, zip

I have 3 very large files(+100 MB) file_hash, cert_hash and url_data each has one string per line. The problem is that size of data in all these files are not same. I have used izip_longest function to read all these files at once (can't load these files in memory) but I wanted to iterate it for the longest file (file_hash is longest) and suppose all data from cert_hash has been read it should start taking the values from beginning of cert_hash file and similarly if url_data got's over it also starts reading from beginning. I have tried using fillvalue parameter but it takes only one value, I wanted to give different value for cert_hash and url_data if they get over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) `cert_hash` and `url_data` if you want them to restart. For example:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle, izip
>>> for t in izip("abcdef", cycle("ghi"), cycle("jklm")):
    print t


('a', 'g', 'j')
('b', 'h', 'k')
('c', 'i', 'l')
('d', 'g', 'm')
('e', 'h', 'j')
('f', 'i', 'k')
```

Note that you no longer use `izip_longest`, as `cycle` is infinite.

---

If you want to restart at the end rather than the start, here is a tweak to the `cycle` equivalent implementation that achieves that:

```
>>> def zigzag(iterable):
    """zigzag('ABCD') --> A B C D C B A B C D  ..."""
    forward = []
    for element in iterable:
        yield element
        forward.append(element)
    backward = forward[-2:0:-1]
    while True:
        for element in backward:
            yield element
        for element in forward:
            yield element


>>> z = zigzag("ABCD")
>>> for _ in range(10):
    print next(z)


A
B
C
D
C
B
A
B
C
D
```

Comment: Accepted your answer but is there anyway to repeat it in reverse order i.e: reverse cycle

Comment: @RoshanMehta do you mean get to the end then start working backwards rather than returning to the beginning?

Comment: Yup, that's is the behavior I actually wanted ;)

Comment: There probably is, but I don't know off the top of my head. Start looking in [the `itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes), maybe? There is also [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed). Should it repeat the last element, or start with the penultimate one?

Comment: I have updated my answer based on the "equivalent implementation" given for `cycle` in the documentation; does that do what you want?

Comment: The slicing thing is not acceptable as I don't know beforehand that how many lines are there in file's.

Comment: Yes but you **do know at that point**, and the indices are relative to the start and end of the list.